# Does Skynet have the ability to copy human memories into Terminators?

Tags: the-terminator-series, the-sarah-connor-chronicles

In [Allison From Palmdale](http://terminator.wikia.com/wiki/Episode_204:_Allison_from_Palmdale), Cameron suffers a glitch and flashes back to some distant memories. In these memories she's a human and was captured by Terminators. We learn that her (human) name was 'Allison Young'.

**When a Terminator copies a specific human's form, does Skynet have the capability of copying their memories as well?**

**Was Cameron flashing back to Allison's *real memories* or were these just generic 'escaped human' memories that Skynet had concocted?**

Comment: I've edited out the wiki link since it doesn't add anything to the question and wasn't supported by a reference.

Comment: I got that impression from that episode.  I figured (**spoiler alert**) it was related to how Skynet interacted with Marcus' memories in *Terminator Salvation* - which is never really fully explained.  (Hopefully that's not too much of a spoiler.)

Comment: Well, if you consider the new model of terminator in Genysis, I would say so. But I suppose that's more of a conversion to terminator than a copy.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**tl;dr:** Assimilation of memories is improbable.

Allison (the real one) was interrogated a lot, which would not have been necessary if a simple memory-copy will<sup>+</sup> have been possible. It is more likely that since the Allison-Terminator (Cameron) had to learn enough about the original to imitate her convincingly to future's John Connor, she *reconstructed* all the relevant memory as if they were real. The glitch then merely caused Cameron to believe those were actual memories, and if the AI is sophisticated enough (it can learn and adapt, after all) it probably simply fills the gap just as humans' subconsciousness does.

Comment: ⁺ Time travel will mess up grammar a lot, didn't it?